# Why is the UITextfield being cut off?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, cut

Does anyone know why the top is being cut off in the below image?

The text is size 40 and both vertical and horiz text alignment is centered
The size of the UITextField frame is 150,70. Are there some sort of padding or gutters that I need to adjust?

Also worth mentioning, the text is an attributed string. Perhaps that makes a difference?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Never seen before.. Is it a custom UITextfield?

Comment: @daniellarsson I did subclass UITextfield. It would be nice to have a solution, but I just for the time being made the text 26.f instead of 40.f so it appears fine